# How to deal with random pop up window in puppeteer js

Tags: puppeteer

I have a pop up window that appears on the page randomly.  Usually about 20 seconds after I go on a page.

```
<div class="bluecoreActionScreen" id="bluecoreActionScreen">
        <form novalidate="novalidate" class="bluecoreEmailCaptureForm" id="bluecoreEmailCaptureForm" name="bluecoreEmailCaptureForm">
            <div class="commonScreenElement" style="width: 550px;height: 500px;display: block;background-color: #181a1cfc;">
<<<< OTHER HTML >>>>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Is the best way to deal with this just to wait for the selector to appear and then click it off?
Or would is there another way to deal with dialogues (popups).

```
await page.waitForSelector('.bluecoreActionScreen');
```

Then click it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use waitForSelector like this:

```
await page.waitForSelector('.bluecoreActionScreen')
```

and then remove the element by CSS or DOM after that:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    let popupElement = document.querySelector('.bluecoreActionScreen')
    // BY CSS DISPLAY NONE
    popupElement.style.display = 'none'
    // OR BY REMOVE THE ELEMENT DOM
    popupElement.parentElement.removeChild(popupElement)
})
```